# how to merge two RDD to one RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Help ,I have two RDDs, i want to merge to one RDD.This is my code.

```
val us1 = sc.parallelize(Array(("3L"), ("7L"),("5L"),("2L")))
val us2 = sc.parallelize(Array(("432L"), ("7123L"),("513L"),("1312L")))
```

Comment: what is your expected output and what have you tried?

Comment: 3L
7L
5L
2L
432L
7123L
513L
1312L

Comment: i want this RDD ,means two RDD merge to one RDD

Comment: val newrdd = us1.++(us2)

Answer (score 12):

Just use union:

```
val merged = us1.union(us2)
```

Documentation is [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@union(other:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T])

Shotcut in Scala is:

```
val merged = us1 ++ us2
```

Comment: @Simon [Please upvote or accept answers rather than leaving thank you comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

You need the `RDD.union`These don't join on a key. Union doesn't really do anything itself, so it is low overhead. Note that the combined RDD will have all the partitions of the original RDDs, so you may want to coalesce after the union.

```
val x = sc.parallelize(Seq( (1, 3), (2, 4) ))
val y = sc.parallelize(Seq( (3, 5), (4, 7) ))
val z = x.union(y)
z.collect
res0: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,3), (2,4), (3,5), (4,7))
```

API

```
def++(other: RDD[T]): RDD[T]
```

Return the union of this RDD and another one.

[def++ API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@++(other:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T])

```
def union(other: RDD[T]): RDD[T]
```

Return the union of this RDD and another one. Any identical elements will appear multiple times (use .distinct() to eliminate them).

[def union API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@union(other:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T])

Comment: why would you want to coalesce afterwards?  If the two input RDDs are properly partitioned, then the union RDD will be too.

Comment: Just for performance and to update the Partition .its not mandate but can be done . It returns a new RDD that is reduced into numPartitions partitions.

Comment: Right, I get what coalesce does.  But if your partitions are correctly sized in both input RDDs, performing a coalesce will produce partitions that are too large (especially if you use the shuffle = false option)

Comment: Then if its partitions correctly done then its all good . your code good to go  :)