# How can I combine multiple RDD[(String, Double, Double)] into one RDD?

Tags: scala

```
for(i <- 1 to 20) {
    val tmp = rdd.sample(true, 1)
    val rdd2 = resampledData(tmp)
    }
```

I would like to combine every rdd2 in the loop in single rdd. The type of rdd2 is RDD[(String, Double, Double)] and how can I initialize the new vriable if required?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to merge two RDD to one RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120341/how-to-merge-two-rdd-to-one-rdd)

Comment: I think it is not duplicate as actually I don't have two RDDs already initialized. I have only one RDD not initialized and I would make recursive merge on this single RDD.

Comment: val combined = (1 to 20).map(x => resampledData(rdd.sample(true, 1))).reduce(_ union _)

Comment: this code solved my problem

Comment: You can put it as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

val combined = (1 to 20).map(x => resampledData(rdd.sample(true, 1))).reduce(_ union _)